# Mongoose: How to create specific field criteria in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to have an advanced search form which takes multiple criteria and includes them in a mongoose search, this is the approach I was thinking

```
router.post('/search/university', function(req, res) {
  var university = req.body.university.toLowerCase();
  var searchCriteria = education_key + ":" + {$RegExp("^" + university)};
  User.find({searchCriteria}, function(err, matching_users){
    res.render('searchresults', {user_array : matching_users, school : req.body.university});
  });
});
```

However, I can't just construct the searchCriteria like this because apparently there are parentheses and such which don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be manipulating this as JavaScript objects rather than trying to build strings:

```
router.post('/search/university', function(req, res) {
  var university = req.body.university.toLowerCase();
  var searchCriteria = { "education_key": {}};

  searchCriteria["education_key"] = { "$regex": "^" + university };

  User.find(searchCriteria, function(err, matching_users){
    res.render('searchresults', {user_array : matching_users, school : req.body.university});
  });
});
```

The [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator is optional but a safe way of making sure the serialization works correctly